# Return 500 from Laravel 7 to Google Cloud Task without abort()

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-tasks

In order for Google Cloud Tasks to automatically be re-queued I need my Laravel 7 app to return a 500 error, but everything short of a call to abort() seems to want to return a 200.  I know that this ought to work:

```
return response('No dice son, you gotta work-a late.', 500);
```

...but no, the task still receives 200 and thus it's deleted from the queue as though it had succeeded.

The reason I'd prefer to avoid `abort('Fall down go boom')` is that it also raises an exception in Stackdriver, and that's unnecessary since I'm returning this particular error when a third party's API fails to provide data.  In the event of errors on my side I'm killing the job outright.

The flow of my code is that I raise a custom exception when the third-party API returns null, then catch that exception and in the handler I call another method that does the work of cleaning up the job, which is when I intended to return 500... though right now I'm calling `abort('No worky')`.

Is there some minutia in the docs that I managed to overlook?

Comment: `return response(, status)`  has to work. If it doesn't there is maybe a middleware of yours interfering / overwriting the res. Also, you need to return that from the ControllerAction that handles the request. Contrary to `abort` it does not work like deeper in service.

Answer (score 2):

In order to send HTTP 500, this usually would be:

```
return abort(500, 'Internal Server Error');
```

And the method usally doesn't matter, as it is just a helper, which returns [`Response`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Http/Response.html).
Changing the error message does not chenge the fact that it's an intenral server error - and when returning 500, it is probably normal to have it logged as an error.